# I have a sandwich for my lunch

Tags: expressions

Does it mean that somebody eats only one sandwich for their lunch?

If somebody eats 2 sandwiches for their lunch it is possible to use this expression? Or only "I eat two sandwiches for my lunch."?

"I have two sandwiches for my lunch" - is it OK if we speak about eating, not having?

> I have a sandwich for my lunch.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally "a sandwich" means "one sandwich".  But the meaning of "one sandwich" is not precise.  If you take a sandwich and cut it in half, does that make two sandwiches, or two half sandwiches?

So while it is possible to say "I have two sandwiches for lunch", the level of precision doesn't justify it.  "I have a sandwich for lunch" or "I have sandwiches for lunch" would be much more common, and I wouldn't be surprised to find the person who said "I have a sandwich" actually eating two halves of a sandwich, or even having two different sandwiches.

Comment: It can also mean, "Today, my lunch is sandwich", can't it?

Answer (score 1):

"A" sandwich means *one* sandwich. It cannot mean two sandwiches.

However, your statement "I have a sandwich for my lunch", depending on the context, could mean either:

- You are currently carrying a sandwich for today's lunch
- You have a sandwich *every day* for your lunch.

If it was the latter, then technically the singular "a sandwich" is referring to all the sandwiches you have eaten and will eat in the future! You can also express the same meaning using a plural, for example: "*I take sandwiches for my lunch*". This could mean you take more than one sandwich daily, or just one.

In British English, we sometimes idiomatically use the plural word "sandwiches" to refer to a packed lunch, so "I've got sandwiches" may mean you have a lunchbox containing a sandwich (or sandwiches) and other items too.

---

If you were to bring a specific number into your statement and say, for example, "I eat two sandwiches for lunch", it does feel like the number if the focus of your statement. It would seem like you were making a point of highlighting that you eat, not one, but two, or three, or however many. Saying "sandwiches" doesn't seem like a big deal, as this may idiomatically refer to just one sandwich, perhaps cut into two anyway.